# Sum of duplicates on Parent row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have landowners in column A and some landowners have multiple rows (because of parcel ID)

[image]

I'm trying to get in column E a total sum of Acres for each Landowner. you can see that rows 3-7 are a landowner with multiple plots of land, and I want in row 3 column E to sum those acres up and place a "-" in the other rows.

How could I do that?

I was thinking something like `=if(a2<>a1,SUM(`, but I don't know how to keep that total sum in just the rows that say `Parent Row` in column D, no rows where column D has "-"

Comment: You could use the Subtotals feature.

Answer (score 1):

Only alternative ways where the first method doesn't requires the need for the `Expand/Collapse` Column and another method where it uses the `Dynamic Array` Features of `MS365` to spill using one single formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),"-")
```

---

Or,

Using Dynamic Array Features:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(7^89,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _LandOwnerName, A2:INDEX(A:A,_lastRow),
     _Acres, C2:INDEX(C:C,_lastRow),
     _ParentRow, D2:INDEX(D:D,_lastRow),
     IF(_ParentRow="Parent Row",SUMIFS(_Acres,_LandOwnerName,_LandOwnerName),"-"))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using `IF` and `SUMIFS`:

```
=IF(D2="Parent Row",SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),"-")
```

[image]